# Como usar o ConstraintLayout no Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, layout

Olá, gostaria de saber como utilizar o ConstraintLayout no Xamarin para Android, uso o Visual Studio Community 2017.

Já instalei os pacotes NuGet, já atualizei meu Android SDK, configurei as versões mínimas do projeto para a 7.1 (API 25) e não consigo usar o ContraintLayout.

Ele não aparece na caixa de ferramentas junto com os outros layouts:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Escreva apenas em português para que fique claro.

Comment: Desculpe mas o que eu perguntei em português, tentei perguntar a mesma coisa em inglês...

Comment: Este é o StackOverflow em português. O objetivo é ter somente perguntas em português para estar em concordância com a comunidade. Edite a pergunta e retire os textos em inglês deixando somente a parte em português

Comment: Pronto, retirei as partes em inglês.

Comment: Tem de instalar o respectivo pacote: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout/

Comment: @ramaral Eu instalei, mas mesmo assim não aparece na caixa de ferramentas, como está no print...